# trouble with sending data in php to SQL, database

Tags: php, mysql, database, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is a snippet of code with some lines commented out. It seems to work if I send one case using all literals (not variables) but when I throw the ". $uid . " and the others in there it does not work. I keep checking the database after each use to see.

```
 <?php // working name and pics
        if ($user) {
        echo "Hello test";
        $arrayOfFriends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
        foreach ($arrayOfFriends['data'] as $value) {
        $uid = $value['id'];
        $name = $value['name'];
        echo $name;
        //create the url
        $profile_pic =  "http://graph.facebook.com/".$uid."/picture?type=large";
        //echo the image out
        echo "<img src=\"" . $profile_pic . "\" />"; 
        echo "<br>";
            //put uid, name, and link to pic in data base 
            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno())
            {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            } else {
                echo "MySQL connects" ;
            }
            //$command = "INSERT INTO  `peoplestorage` (  `ID` ,  `UID` ,  `name` ,  `piclink` ,  `scoop1` ,  `scoop2` ,  `scoop3` ) VALUES ( '' ,".$uid.",".$name.",".$profile_pic.",'','','')";
            //$command = "INSERT INTO  `peoplestorage` (  `ID` ,  `UID` ,  `name` ,  `piclink` ,  `scoop1` ,  `scoop2` ,  `scoop3` ) VALUES ('' ,  '444567',  'hoop22',  'link to poictiure ',  'hero',  'big ol',  '')";
            //echo $command;
            mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO  `peoplestorage` (  `ID` ,  `UID` ,  `name` ,  `piclink` ,  `scoop1` ,  `scoop2` ,  `scoop3` ) VALUES ( '' ,".$uid.",".$name.",".$profile_pic.",'','','')");

        }   


            //testing inputting data 

            //$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM  `peoplestorage` LIMIT 0 , 30");
            //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            //{
            //echo $row['ID'] . " " . $row['name'];
            //echo "<br>";
            //}


        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Where's your quotation marks around the dynamic values? You're using `"` but no `'` around the double quotation marks. It should be something more like `'".$uid."'` and not `".$uid."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into parameterized queries, this will negate this problem.

You problem stems from the fact that you are not quoting your variable string.

```
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO  `peoplestorage` (  `ID` ,  `UID` ,  `name` ,  `piclink` ,  `scoop1` ,  `scoop2` ,  `scoop3` ) VALUES ( '' ,'".$uid."','".$name."','".$profile_pic."','','','')");
```

Comment: Thank you. I copied and pasted this code into my program and it is working like a charm. Thanks. I would vote up but it wont let me.

Comment: don't just copy/paste. Understand what is going on.

Comment: Yes Wise teacher. I took your advice, after doing some looking around. So the method that you helped me create is hack-able with SQL injection, and if this is the case I should do it another method. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use a prepared statement instead, it's much cleaner and also prevents SQL Injection:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO  `peoplestorage` (  `ID` ,  `UID` ,  `name` ,  `piclink` ,  `scoop1` ,  `scoop2` ,  `scoop3` ) VALUES ('',?,?,?,'','','')";

$stmt = $link->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('iss', $uid, $name, $profile_pic);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```